# Any PC or web applications similar to PhotoPills?

Tags: sunlight, sun, sunrise, golden-hour

Is there any PC or web applications similar to [PhotoPills](http://www.photopills.com/) to calculate golden hour and twilight?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [SunCalc](http://suncalc.net).

Probably one of the prettier browser based ones out there.

[image: SunCalc Screenshot]

Comment: Nice! I think this one obsoletes the first link in my answer.

Comment: This project although still live, seems to be suffering the google maps API "for development purposes only" situation, and may not be actively supported as a welcome message states "Note (Oct 2018): I'm aware of the broken map (see this article for more context). Stay tuned — I'm working on a new version!

Answer (score 5):

The Photographer's Ephemeris (http://photoephemeris.com/). The desktop version is a web app, and they also have iOS and Android versions. I plan every 'proper' shoot I do with it.

Comment: I used this on occasion, as it was free and had no sign in or anything, but times change. It's now a "web app" meaning you have to create an (admittedly still free) login. But I'd rather not.

Comment: I just use PhotoPills these days. Not a desktop solution but I rarely use a desktop tbh.

Answer (score 1):

I find the following websites to be useful:

- [Calculation of sun’s position in the sky for each location on the earth at any time of day](http://www.sunearthtools.com/dp/tools/pos_sun.php)
- [Twilight Calculator - "Blue Hour / Golden Hour Table"](http://jekophoto.eu/tools/twilight-calculator-blue-hour-golden-hour/index.php)

The first is aimed more towards solar panel installation than photography, but gives information about sun angle that the second, more popular site doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

SunCalc.org looks very similar to suncalc.net from the answer by TLC.
[image: suncalc.org]